# AngularJS : Incorrect Alignment using ng-repeat and ng-include

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat and inside it an include for a different html partial.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in feedItems">
  <div ng-include="'item.itemType.html'">
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is my css of partial html itemType.html

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 2px 0 2px;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
```

Now ng-repeat div does not have any fixed size. what I want is to align the ng-repeat items properly according to the size.

Though i dont have enough reputation I am not able to post an image over here.

As of now we can imagine the output to be like 3 html divs among which 2nd div has a slightly increased hieght are placed side by side  and a 4th div placed below the third. Whereas the 4th div should be aligned to the left below the first div.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How many `<div>` fit in one line?

Comment: there can be atmost 3 divs in one line

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes, It did solve my problem partially, just have to check out whether i can dynamically fit the divs on screen resize.

Comment: Which part remains problematic? Attaching DOM maniuplation actions to the wind.resize-event is usually not a good idea, at least perfromancewise. In most cases it show a lack of CSS knowledge which is very common among developers of e.g. Java.

Comment: Responsive UI, Maybe for that I will have to use css columns, right ?

Comment: You mean on bigger screens, more `<div>` will fit in one line?

Comment: Use media queries for that. Ask a new question and I will answer.

Comment: Ok.Thanks connexo for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.card:nth-of-type(3n+1) { clear: left; }
```

If you need to support browsers that do not recognize :nth-of-type (http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-of-type), you will have to find a way to apply an additional css class `.clear` to every 4th item:

```
.card.clear { clear: left; }
```

This will lead to a visual representation as follows:

[image: 4 DIV floating left, 4th clearing float]

If what you want to achieve rather looks like

[image: 4 DIV as Columns]

you will have to find a completely different solution, for example using css columns.